# SQL Oracle - Higher than a letter and number

Tags: oracle, text, comparison

I am writing to you because I need a help for a join with SQL Oracle.

Actually, I do a join with sometinh like that :

```
database1 left outer join database2 on database1.name = database2.name and database2.date = 'A14'
```

**A14** means "2014".

What I need to do is to change the end of this join, to include "**A14**", but also the coming years (**A15, A16, A17, ...**).

Can you help me to find how ?
Thanks lot !

Olivier

Comment: Do you really have a *table* called *database*? Strange naming style...

Comment: Of course not, but I used this to be more explicit.

Comment: Calling a table a database doesn't strike me as "explicit". Those are two very different things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a finite range of years you can use the predicate OR:

```
select * 
  from database1 
  left outer join database2 on database1.name = database2.name 
                           and (database2.date = 'A14' OR database2.date = 'A15' OR database2.date = 'A16' OR ...)
```

If you use an infinite range you can use ">=":

```
select * 
  from database1 
  left outer join database2 on database1.name = database2.name and database2.date >= 'A14'
```

Comment: I like this answer better. Using ">=".

Answer (score 0):

This should work until A99. If you get into B's, this will fail.

```
to_number(substr('A14',2)) >= 14
```

or

```
to_number(replace(database2.date,'A','20')) >= 2014
```